# How to fix /core/index/notFound

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, css

I have been working on a Magento 2 development project for a few months now, and until recently, there have been no issues. When I started it up today, though, my main css file came back as this: `<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://mysite.localhost/core/index/notFound" />` and none of the main css site css is working. The css for the other extensions still work, only the main site's styles.css file isn't working.

I have flushed cache, ran setup:upgrade, s:s:d, setup:di:compile, composer update and nothing has worked to get rid of this error. No errors are being logged as well. I have searched everywhere, but I have not been able to find anything relating to this particular error, especially since it was working just fine yesterday.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not exactly. I restarted the server and everything started working again.